# Trying to create different hover underlines for each of my header tabs

Tags: css

I'm trying to recreate the bbc website for a class and I'm stuck on a very annoying header issue. I'm trying to get a border to appear beneath the entire div (Each section of the header has a separate div). But my code is making the border show up only above the words in the div. This is the style sheet so far, it's all relevant and working.

**EDIT:** I've experimented with `a#tab-1:hover` and `a#tab-1`, but didn't include any of the unnecessary code. So far this right here is what I have. The earlier styling seems necessary for the entire header to stay formatted correctly, so I'm not sure if it's having a contradictory effect on the link formatting.

```css
.topbar-section {

  float:left;
  border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
  height:100%

}

#login-logo {

  width:25px;
  margin:10px 15px;
  float:left;
}

#signin {

  font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  align:left;

}

#signin-text{

  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:90%;
  position:relative;
  top:16px;

}

      a#tab-1:hover {
  border-bottom: solid yellow;
  size:100%
}

a#tab-1 {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="signin" class="topbar-section">
    <a href="" id="tab-1">
      <img src="login.png" id="login-logo">
      <span id="signin-text">Sign in</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: 1. Seperate your CSS from your HTML.
2. Create a working code snippet, and it would be much easier to help you...

Comment: Done, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but let me know if I'm getting warm.

```css
.topbar-section ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topbar-section li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
}

.topbar-section li:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="signin" class="topbar-section">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">third</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, actually. So should I rewrite my classes into an unordered list or should I make this supplemental?

Comment: Going to play with this right now and let you know if it works.